# ES6 Structuring Assignment?

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, ecmascript-6, destructuring

The new destructuring assignment features of [ES6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) are fairly well known now ([live copy](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Alet%20a%2C%20b%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Existing%20variables%0Alet%20o%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%20%22a%22%2C%20b%3A%20%22b%22%7D%3B%20%2F%2F%20An%20object%20to%20get%20values%20from%0A%2F%2F%20...%0A(%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%20%3D%20o)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Set%20them%20to%20the%20props%20from%20%60o%60%0Aconsole.log(a)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22a%22%0Aconsole.log(b)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22b%22) on Babel's REPL); in the case of variables that *already* exist:

```
let a, b;                 // Existing variables
let o = {a: "a", b: "b"}; // An object to get values from
// ...
({a, b} = o);             // Set them to the props from `o`
console.log(a);           // "a"
console.log(b);           // "b"
```

Is there a *simple* converse in ES6? Setting properties on an **existing** object based on variables with the same name? (Other than the obvious `o.a = a; o.b = b;`)

Note I'm not talking about when *creating* an object, we could do that with the wonderful new object initializer syntax that lets us not repeat the names unnecessarily:

```
let a = "a";
let b = "b";
let o = {a, b};
```

But if I *already* have an object, can I do some kind of *structuring* assignment in ES6?

Comment: It sounds like you want the object initializer shorthand to be able to `extend` existing objects. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Mathletics: Or some other mechanism with that sort of result, yes.

Comment: I'm not getting your question. So you have an existing object `{a : "a"}`. You have a variable b with the value "b". What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @torazaburo: *(Sorry, editing error in my earlier comment made it clear as mud.)* Starting with `a`, `b`, and `o` where `o` refers to an object, I want the result I'd get with `o.a = a; o.b = b;` via some kind of structuring syntax. E.g., as I said above, the converse of how `({a, b} = o);` in ES6 lets me get what I'd get from `a = o.a; b = o.b;` in ES5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi: It's definitely *similar*, but not quite th same. My starting point isn't two objects, it's variables and an object. Solutions may well require a temporary object (mine below does), but I was frankly hoping for a solution that didn't. Call it "related." :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The closest I've come up with is to use `Object.assign` and a temporary object ([live copy](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20%22a%22%2C%20b%20%3D%20%22b%22%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20The%20variables%0Alet%20obj%20%3D%20%7Bc%3A%20%22c%22%7D%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20The%20existing%20object%0AObject.assign(obj%2C%20%7Ba%2C%20b%7D)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%22Structuring%22%20assignment%2C%20sort%20of%0Aconsole.log(JSON.stringify(obj))%3B%20%2F%2F%20%22%7B%22c%22%3A%22c%22%2C%22a%22%3A%22a%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22b%22%7D%0A)):

```
let a = "a", b = "b";             // The variables
let obj = {c: "c"};               // The existing object
Object.assign(obj, {a, b});       // "Structuring" assignment, sort of
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // "{"c":"c","a":"a","b":"b"}
```

It's fairly simple, but it's a function call and a temporary object.

---

<s>**Update:** [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897961/es6-structuring-assignment#comment49838403_30898609) that [there's a strawman proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:define_properties_operator) **(link now dead)** for a `:=` operator that will do this, and one of their first use cases is indeed the use case that primarily lead me to this question: Constructors:</s>

```
// From strawman proposal linked above, doesn't actually exist yet!
class Point {
   constructor(x,y) {
      this := {x,y}  //define and initialize x and y properties of new object
      //   ^^
   }
}
```

So given that strawman exists, I suspect for now the `assign` is going to be the best I can do in ES6. The old wiki with the strawman is offline, and there's nothing about `:=` in the [proposals repo](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Comment: There isn't anything I can think of better than this. At the end of the day, shorthand object properties are the only way to collapse key and value, so creating a temporary object is necessary.

Comment: @loganfsmyth: Thanks. ES6 is so rich that I was wondering if I'd missed something. I half expected to get a near-instant reply pointing to something obvious and feel like a dolt. :-)

Comment: This is as close as you're gonna get

Comment: It's not bad at all :) For what it's worth objects should generally keep a structure so this sort of pattern is useful (at least until we figure more uses) in one place in particular - the constructor where it can be a very clean options object merge or assignment . Like https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/f105209f1a6274aad550

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: And that's after all the [games you can play](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30863086/157247) with destructured arguments and default values! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Some experimental stuff, building on top of your answer.

If you wanted to get a little cheeky you could emulate the assignment portion of it with a setter. Definitely not practical, but it's a fun way to see what the behaviour *might* look like on the outside, if maybe you could empty assign `o[] =`. ([Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=%22use%20strict%22%3B%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20'1'%2C%20b%20%3D%20'2'%3B%0Alet%20o%20%3D%20%7Bz%3A%20'26'%7D%3B%0A%0AObject.defineProperty(Object.prototype%2C%20''%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20set%3A%20function%20(o)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20o)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%2C%20configurable%3A%20true%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Ao%5B''%5D%20%3D%20%7Ba%2C%20b%7D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(o)%3B))

```
let a = '1', b = '2';
let o = {z: '26'};

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, '', {
  set: function (o) {
    Object.assign(this, o);
  }, configurable: true
});

o[''] = {a, b};
```

Same issues you face with your answer, actually more, but some food for thought.

Comment: My eyes hurt. Creative, though.