# How to create an object with some array values without saving reference to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, type-conversion, aggregate

In other words; how can I convert

```
// an array of length >= 3
let myArray = returnOfSomeParametricFunction(); // assuming repeating rhs removes dryness

let myObj = { staticKeyName: myArray[1], anotherStaticKeyName: myArray[2] };
```

to a single liner. Perhaps something like:

```
let myObj = returnOfSomeParametricFunction().reduce(arr=> { staticKeyName: arr[1], anotherStaticKeyName: arr[2] };
```

Comment: Note that array indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: People really need to get over "single liner"s...

Comment: Like `(a => ({ staticKeyName: a[1], anotherStaticKeyName: a[2] }))(returnOfSomeParametricFunction())`?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, exactly. Thanks.

Comment: From the above, `const [,staticKeyName,anotherStaticKeyName] = returnOfSomeParametricFunction();`

Comment: @HereticMonkey But they're not trying to make variables named `staticKeyName` and `anotherStaticKeyName`.  Those are intended to be property names

Comment: So more like [Destructure array to object property keys](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38242744/215552) then?

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate of that one.  Surprised not to see the arrow function solution in there though.

Comment: Ah, the other one doesn't have the constraint that the array not be a named variable.  I guess it's not quite a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if I needed to do it in one line and not introduce a new variable in the same scope as `myObj`, and I didn't care about readability, I'd use an arrow function like this:

```
let myObj = (a => ({ staticKeyName: a[1], anotherStaticKeyName: a[2] }))(
  returnOfSomeParametricFunction());
```

You can verify that `myObj` has the properties of the right types.  For example, given

```
declare function returnOfSomeParametricFunction(): [Date, number, string];
```

Then `myObj` would have type:

```
/*
let myObj: {
    staticKeyName: number;
    anotherStaticKeyName: string;
}
*/
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzg2RlQHlEBlHAWxAAVYpaMYswAxNTXVACgEoAXPADaAESgYQAGnipk1AEYgYsgM4ssqAOYBdANwAoQxBAZ41AJ6lFAK3gBeeLyiOAfM4De8DZLYBpEEsAOSYQYSgRAEZdWShUHAwACxUKDD8wQJCwiJEAJl14AF9+fl5DeAIzYjJKGnpGZlYOLmw8AX5jAHoAKhMzC2s7YU8Kyp907Eyg0NpheSUVI3H4eMSUmDSMrNnwidYdIyLDHq74IA)